# Formatting Javascript Object to new Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am having a few issues formatting data in the way I require it.  At the moment, I have an empty function

```
populateAddresses(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

This outputs the full data which takes the following format

```
{
  "county": "WEST MIDLANDS",
  "town": "SOLIHULL",
  "streets": [
    {
      "name": "MARSLAND ROAD",
      "numbers": [
        {
          "buildingNumberOrName": "1",
          "buildingName": "",
          "subBuildingName": "",
          "buildingNumber": "1"
        },
        {
          "buildingNumberOrName": "3",
          "buildingName": "",
          "subBuildingName": "",
          "buildingNumber": "3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "postcode": "B92 7BU"
}
```

So it is basically the addresses for a postcode.  What I am trying to do is create an array of complete addresses.  So for the above example, my array would be something like this

```
["1 MARSLAND ROAD, SOLIHULL, WEST MIDLANDS, B92 7BU", "3 MARSLAND ROAD, SOLIHULL, WEST MIDLANDS, B92 7BU"]
```

So it will be buildingNumberOrName + streets name, then town, county and postcode.  There could be more than one street, which could potentially complicate things a bit further?

I was thinking about maybe looping the Object to get the information, something like

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {

});
```

But then I think I will have to many inner loops.  I have seen mapping, but not sure how this could be used here?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do you have more object, like `data`? what should happen then?

Comment: What about `buildName` and `subBuildingName`? will they always be empty? and will `buildNumber` always be the same as `buildingNumberOrName`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a problem to have nested loops for this. Your data only really has two levels (streets and numbers), so nested loops do the trick clearly and easily:

```
const array = [];
const {county, town, postcode} = data;
for (const {name, numbers} of data.streets) {
    for (const {buildingNumberOrName} of numbers) {
        array.push(`${buildingNumberOrName} ${name} ${town}, ${county}, ${postcode}`);
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = {
  "county": "WEST MIDLANDS",
  "town": "SOLIHULL",
  "streets": [
    {
      "name": "MARSLAND ROAD",
      "numbers": [
        {
          "buildingNumberOrName": "1",
          "buildingName": "",
          "subBuildingName": "",
          "buildingNumber": "1"
        },
        {
          "buildingNumberOrName": "3",
          "buildingName": "",
          "subBuildingName": "",
          "buildingNumber": "3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "postcode": "B92 7BU"
};

const array = [];
const {county, town, postcode} = data;
for (const {name, numbers} of data.streets) {
    for (const {buildingNumberOrName} of numbers) {
        array.push(`${buildingNumberOrName} ${name} ${town}, ${county}, ${postcode}`);
    }
}

console.log(array);
```

That works just fine if there are multiple streets, assuming the structure of the object for subsequent entries in `streets` is the same as the one you've shown.

Or if you need to stick to ES5 or earlier:

```
var array = [];
var county = data.county, town = data.town, postcode = data.postcode;
data.streets.forEach(function(street) {
    var name = street.name;
    street.numbers.forEach(function(num) {
        array.push(num.buildingNumberOrName + " " + name + " " + town + ", " + county + ", " + postcode);
    });
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var data = {
  "county": "WEST MIDLANDS",
  "town": "SOLIHULL",
  "streets": [
    {
      "name": "MARSLAND ROAD",
      "numbers": [
        {
          "buildingNumberOrName": "1",
          "buildingName": "",
          "subBuildingName": "",
          "buildingNumber": "1"
        },
        {
          "buildingNumberOrName": "3",
          "buildingName": "",
          "subBuildingName": "",
          "buildingNumber": "3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "postcode": "B92 7BU"
};

var array = [];
var county = data.county, town = data.town, postcode = data.postcode;
data.streets.forEach(function(street) {
    var name = street.name;
    street.numbers.forEach(function(num) {
        array.push(num.buildingNumberOrName + " " + name + " " + town + ", " + county + ", " + postcode);
    });
});

console.log(array);
```

---

That follows the rule from your question about the output:

> ...buildingNumberOrName + streets name, then town, county and postcode...

but you can mix in the other properties from the objects in the `numbers` array as necessary when creating the string.

Answer (score 3):

You could collect all information and push string to the result set. This works for more than one object.

```js
var data = [{ county: "WEST MIDLANDS", town: "SOLIHULL", streets: [{ name: "MARSLAND ROAD", numbers: [{ buildingNumberOrName: "1", buildingName: "", subBuildingName: "", buildingNumber: "1" }, { buildingNumberOrName: "3", buildingName: "", subBuildingName: "", buildingNumber: "3" }] }], postcode: "B92 7BU" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { county, town, streets, postcode }) => {
        streets.forEach(({ name, numbers }) =>
            numbers.forEach(({ buildingNumberOrName }) =>
                r.push(`${buildingNumberOrName} ${name}, ${town}, ${county}, ${postcode}`)
            )
        );
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer your question without knowing what you want to do when there are several streets, but in general that looks like a case where you would

- use map() and template strings to convert objects to strings, and then
- join() to merge these strings into a single string.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution from complexity point of view.... but if you will have the same structure of streets array, this will solve the problem.

```js
let jsonData = {
  "country": "WEST MIDLANDS",
  "town": "SOLIHULL",
  "streets": [{
    "name": "MARSLAND ROAD",
    "numbers": [{
        "buildingNumberOrName": "1",
        "buildingName": "",
        "subBuildingName": "",
        "buildingNumber": "1"
      },
      {
        "buildingNumberOrName": "3",
        "buildingName": "",
        "subBuildingName": "",
        "buildingNumber": "3"
      }
    ]
  }],
  "postcode": "B92 7BU"
}

let fullAdress = "";
let listOfAdress = []

for (let street of jsonData.streets) {

  let strNumbers = street.numbers;

  for (let building of strNumbers) {
    fullAdress = building.buildingNumberOrName + " " + street.name + ", " + 
                  jsonData.town + ", " +
                  jsonData.country + ", " +
                  jsonData.postcode;
                  
    listOfAdress.push(fullAdress);
  }
  
}

console.log(listOfAdress)
```